# Создание собственного списка пользователем

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data

Пытаюсь сделать для себя тестовое приложение, с использование `Spring Data MongoDB`.
Хочу сделать, чтоб пользователь мог создавать собственные списки. 
[image: Как выглядит база в RoboMongo]

```
@Document()


public class ToDo {
    @Id
    private Object id;
    private List<Item> day;
    private List<Item> week;
    private List<Item> month;
    private List<Item> year;
    private List<Item> other;

    ToDo(){
        this.id = new ObjectId();
        this.day = new ArrayList<>();
        this.week = new ArrayList<>();
        this.month = new ArrayList<>();
        this.year = new ArrayList<>();
        this.other = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    private class Item {

        @Id
        private Object id;
        private boolean completed;
        private String description;
        private Date date;

        public Item(String description, boolean completed) {
            this.description = description;
            this.completed = completed;
            this.date = new Date();
            this.id = new ObjectId(date);
        }
    }

    public void createItem(String name){
        new Item(name, false);
    }
}
```

Нормально ли то, что получается не совсем Pojo модель, она ведь не обязательна при использовании Spring? И вообще при такой модели, возможно создание собственных списков, ну и добавление-перемещение оттуда объектов? Или лучше не создавать такие списки и придумать другой подход?